# How to show dynamic object DataTable data in DataGridView in MVVM logic with Xamarin Froms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dynamic, datagridview, devexpress

I want to fill my datagridview from viewmodel. When I try to fill inside detailpage.cs it works well but in viewmodel it does not work.

DetailPage.xaml

```
var str = await serviceManager.DynamicReports();
        str = str.Replace(@"\", "");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, (typeof(DataTable)));
        dataTable.ItemsSource = dt;
```

DetailPageViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<dynamic> DynamicRaporList
    {
        get
        {
            if (dynamicRaporList == null)
                dynamicRaporList = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
            return dynamicRaporList;
        }
        set
        {
            dynamicRaporList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
async void filldynamicraporlist()
    {


        
        var str = await serviceManager.DynamicReports();
        str = str.Replace(@"\", "");

        if (str != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("VERİ ALINDI");
           
        }
       
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, (typeof(DataTable)));

        DynamicRaporList.Add(dt); 

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
```

*DynamicRaporList.Add(dt);*
I can't figure out this part. I'm not sure I could explain my problem well but I will be glad if anyone help.

Comment: Your two examples are using completely different data types for ItemsSource

Comment: It comes from **serviceManager** . I declared it as str. I have to add data come from serviceManager to **ObservableCollection<dynamic> DynamicRaporList**

Comment: the one that works uses `DataTable`, the one that doesn't uses `ObservableCollection<dynamic>`.  Why aren't you using the same type in both cases?

Comment: I can show ObservableCollection on DataGridView (DevExpress Component). Actually I didn't try use directly datatable on DataGridView. Does it take as a source datatable ?